# How to return an array literal in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying the following code. The line with the error is pointed out.

```
int[] myfunction()
{
    {
      //regular code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                    
       return {0,0,0}; //gives error
    }
}
```

How can I return an array literal like string literals?

Comment: It's also worth nothing that C# doesn't actually have array literals, but an array initialization syntax - to which the accepted answer refers. Literals are special in that they can be directly serialized, and can be assigned to `const` fields. This is not the case with array initialization syntax.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Return an array of `int` like this:

```
return new int [] { 0, 0, 0 };
```

You can also [implicitly type the array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) - the compiler will infer it should be `int[]` because it contains only `int` values:

```
return new [] { 0, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: Woah ho, I didn't know you could implicitly type arrays! +1

Comment: I found that `new int [] {0,0,0}` also works. It would be clearer in my opinion.

Comment: @sgarg That seems to be identical to the answer. And I disagree, implicit typing of the array means changing the constants to floating point would automatically get the correct array type.

Comment: Answer should include an important precision for beginners: this is *not*, in fact, a literal. Whenever this is called, a new array instance will be created and allocated.

Answer (score 12):

Blorgbeard is correct, but you also might think about using the new for .NET 4.0 Tuple class. I found it's easier to work with when you have a set number of items to return. As in if you always need to return 3 items in your array, a 3-int tuple makes it clear what it is.

```
return new Tuple<int,int,int>(0,0,0);
```

or simply

```
return Tuple.Create(0,0,0);
```

Comment: If you have a variable number of items but want some extra functionality you can also do: `return new List<int>(new int[]{0,0,0});`

Comment: @Dave wouldn't `List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 3))` be better?

Comment: @NetMage It would be better if you wanted to vary the number of items, certainly.

Comment: If you want a list with initial content you would be better using `return new List<int> { 0, 0, 0 };`. There is no need for the intermediary array.

Answer (score 10):

if the array has a fixed size and you wante to return a new one filled with zeros

```
return new int[3];
```